# Why doesn't Ubuntu 18.04 show all available applications when you select "All", and how can you make it truly show all of them?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Now that Ubuntu 18 uses Gnome for the graphical shell, running "Show Applications" from the launcher only lists 35 applications for "All" even though there are way more available. The only options are "Frequent" and "All" which doesn't show even half

[image]

This is very deceptive and limiting. By contrast, Unity shows literally all available applications, the graphical ones that is.

For example, "Image Viewer" and "Screenshot" can be found if you search for them, but otherwise they aren't displayed. Not much point in being able to search for something if you don't know it exists in the first place.

How can you truly get all the applications to be displayed from the launcher?

Answer (score 4):

Both in Unity and in the GNOME Shell the Application Overview does *not* display applications: it displays `.desktop` files from a small set of directories, specifically `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`. Both Unity and GNOME Shell display all the `.desktop` files found in these locations which are consistent with being launched as applications and are not explicitly hidden.

What GNOME Shell has (by default), and Unity doesn't, is the ability to group some of the application icons into folders, similar to the way application icons are managed on a mobile phone. In particular, Image Viewer and Screenshot are by default placed [in a folder named Utilities](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/add-categories-to-gnome-shell-dashboard) (or some other name in languages other than English). Click on this folder's icon in the Application Overview and it will open showing the application icons inside.

If you don't like application folders then it is not very difficult to [make GNOME Shell forget about them](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/94378/how-to-make-customized-gnome-app-folders-settings-persistent/).

Comment: Thanks. The naming scheme can be a bit counter-intuitive, and isn't always easy to get clarification for. For starters, the title "Application Summary" would have helped tremendously as a search handle, but I can't find the term on my system. Additionally, if the words "Show Applications" are displayed for this dash icon, it should lead me to believe that it shows (or displays) applications, because that's exactly what it says. Perhaps it would be better to say "Show Desktop Applications" or something to indicate it won't necessarily show all possible applications to be found in the system.

Comment: I deleted my other comment and reposted because it said I could only edit for 5 minutes, and I had to edit  because I pressed enter for a new paragraph before I was finished, which posted the comment, and I'm getting used to posting here. You may want to delete and repost your so our string is coherent.

Comment: @Anthonyd: Oh, I believe that the official name of that view is "Applications Overview". I will edit the answer. At least under this name one can find extensions pertaining specifically to this view. P.S. Here is the [specification of .desktop files](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/).

Comment: "Applications Overview" is the one. But, how could I find that? I even resorted to running `xprop WM_CLASS` to no avail. I hate having to rely on Google searches for these matters.